# Как заставить php скрипт выполнить процедуру?

Tags: php

http://pastebin.com/u8U0Wq28 - сам php скрипт.
http://pastebin.com/rkk6cJgw - процедура.

В общем, это скрипт активации регистрации. Хотелось бы, чтобы исполнялась процедура. Помогите, пожалуйста, проблема в переменной в процедуре и в том, куда и как это вставить в скрипт.

**Обновление**

Выбор переменной не знаю как указать, select * from `users` WHERE `name`='$Login' стоит сейчас, нужно брать информацию из столбца name и коем-то образом вставить в сам php скрипт процедуру. В общем, выдает ошибку

> Notice: Undefined variable: Login in
> /var/www/pw/modules/registration/activate.php
> on line 52

Пробововал `".es($row['name'])."` - тоже выдает ошибки, вероятнее всего, я не туда вставляю процедуру. В общем, первая ошибка в `select * from`users`WHERE`name`='$Login'` в переменной логина, вторая - куда это дело все вставлять:

> Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql
> extension is deprecated and will be
> removed in the future: use mysqli or
> PDO instead in
> /var/www/pw/modules/registration/activate.php
> on line 58
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied
> for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO) in
> /var/www/pw/modules/registration/activate.php
> on line 58
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the
> server could not be established in
> /var/www/pw/modules/registration/activate.php
> on line 58
>
> Warning: mysql_result() expects
> parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
> given in
> /var/www/pw/modules/registration/activate.php
> on line 59

```
 $mysqlresult = mysql_query("SELECT * from `users` WHERE `name` = '".es($row['name'])."'");
       $User_ID = mysql_result($mysqlresult,0,'ID');
       $gold_cnt = 100000000;
       q("
    CALL usecash('$User_ID',1,0,1,0,'$gold_cnt',1,@error)") or die ('Голд не выдан.<br/>Возможные причины:<br/>- Не залиты процедуры<br/>- Голд уже есть в базе на этом аккаунте'
    );
```

Comment: @hekut146, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
$User_ID=mysql_query("select ID from users WHERE name='".$Login."'");
/*если имена пользователей уникальны, то выберется один логин c конкретным ID.
перед подстановкой логина проверьте его на отсутствие вредных символов.
Но не мешало бы в скриптах и процедурах писать комментарии.
*/
```

Дальше опять делаем запрос селектом, а есть ли у пользователя голд

```
/*делаем запрос к соответстующей таблице (таблицам)*/
```